# Web Service can't be accessed in Java code, but its wsdl can be normally seen from Chrome

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans, wsdl

everybody!

I encountered a very strange problem. I have wrote one web service example in Netbeans. In the Netbeans IDE, the web service client and the web service run fluently, if a little slowly. But after being deployed at Tomcat 7.0, the web service can't be assessed normally by the client.

The url for wsdl is `http://221.207.220.12:7001/InterWebService/InterService.wsdl?wsdl`, which can be seen through Chrome.

Following are the exception information:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException:      HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:117)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:208)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.news(Unknown Source)
       at Main.news(Main.java:19)
       at Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
       at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1146)
       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1281)
       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1256)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:104)
       ... 15 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 23 seconds)*
```

Looking for somebody's help! And thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the WebService work when you run it with SoapUI?

Comment: Looks like proxy server somwhere in the middle. Your Chrome knows about it and your java isn't.

Comment: Just read the exception message, it's a network issue. In case the Tomcat is on a remote machine, try to ping or traceroute the the endpoint IP / Hostname.

Comment: Btw: WSDL and service endpoint are not necessarily the same... I can access your WSDL. And have a look at the SOAP address in your WSDL - I cannot access that one.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah. In Netbeans, I deploy the web service on the default Glassfish server, then the client can access the web service without any error.

Comment: @YXHJ513 That isn't what I asked. Does the remote WebService work (that you are asking about here) when you run it with a different client? Have you checked your proxy settings?

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov You guess it! There is one web service running somewhere, but to access it, digital verification is needed. So we develop a intermediate web service. The aim is to let people outside access the web service freely.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry, I am such a newbie about web service that I can't catch what you said. I access the web service via soap method.

Comment: @home I have tried some web service program in Netbeans with ease. Just provide the wsdl address, after some operation, the Netbeans does the most thing. But this one is obviously different. I don't know where the difference comes from.

Answer (score 2):

I have also come across similar kind of issue and found root cause which is as below:

While investigating root cause of the issue, found that “soap:address” of “wsdl:port” element in WSDL file is referring to url which is not matching with url through which are calling web service. This is not correct based on SOAP specification.

On our environment, “soap:address” is referring ‘reverse proxy’ url(i.e. "xxx.com:9040/service.asmx") in wsdl file which is not actual url through which we are trying to access Ace service (i.e. "xxx.com/service.asmx")

Comment: I have requested for change in url and able to access service now. :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to configure your proxy into your Java client code. You can do that with something like,

```
String proxyHost = "192.168.2.2";
String proxyPort = "3128";
System.out.println("Setting up with proxy: " + proxyHost + ":" + proxyPort);
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "localhost|127.0.0.1");
```

Assuming your proxy is at "192.168.2.2:3128". You need to do this once at start-up, I believe before you access any HTTP connections.

Comment: If your proxy needs authentication you can do by implementing an Authenticator like this: Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("<user>", "<pass>".toCharArray());
            }
        };
        Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);